# How to create a contact form delete button in java to delete selected element?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, jlist

I am a beginner who is struggling to create a button in my contact form project in java on IntelliJ. I am trying to achieve this: when the button is clicked, the name is deleted from list on the left and all of the text fields are cleared. I would highly appreciate your help if you decide to provide some guidance. Thank You in advance :)

```java
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Screen extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panelTop;
    private JPanel PanelLeft;
    private JPanel PanelRight;
    private JList listPeople;
    private JButton buttonNew;
    private JButton buttonSave;
    private JTextField textName;
    private JTextField textEmail;
    private JTextField textPhone;
    private JTextField textAddress;
    private JLabel labelAge;
    private JTextField textDateOfBirth;
    private JPanel panelMain;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private ArrayList<Person> people;
    private DefaultListModel listPeopleModel;

    Screen() {
        super("My contacts project"); //calling a parent class for ex dog (subclass) and animal (superclass); Screen=subclass
        this.setContentPane(this.panelMain); //
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //closes the application frame; application not killed
        this.pack(); //sets the frame so that all its contents are at or above their preferred sizes alternatives:setSize and setBound
        people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        listPeopleModel = new DefaultListModel();
        listPeople.setModel(listPeopleModel);
        buttonSave.setEnabled(false);

        buttonNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //activates the click
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //activates the click+`
                Person p = new Person(
                        textName.getText(),
                        textEmail.getText(),
                        textPhone.getText(),
                        textAddress.getText(),
                        textDateOfBirth.getText()
                );
                people.add(p);
                refreshPeopleList();
            }
        });
        buttonSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int personNumber = listPeople.getSelectedIndex();
                if (personNumber >=0){
                    Person p = people.get(personNumber);
                    p.setName(textName.getText());
                    p.setEmail(textEmail.getText());
                    p.setPhoneNumber(textPhone.getText());
                    p.setAddress(textAddress.getText());
                    p.setDateOfBirth(textDateOfBirth.getText());
                    refreshPeopleList();
                }
            }
        });
        listPeople.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int personNumber =  listPeople.getSelectedIndex();
                if(personNumber >= 0) {
                    Person p = people.get(personNumber);
                    textName.setText(p.getName());
                    textEmail.setText(p.getEmail());
                    textPhone.setText(p.getPhoneNumber());
                    textAddress.setText(p. getAddress());
                    textDateOfBirth.setText(p.getDateOfBirth().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY")));
                    labelAge.setText(Integer.toString(p.getAge()) + "years");
                    buttonSave.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    buttonSave.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });

        deleteButton.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                super.keyPressed(e);
                int personNumber =  listPeople.getSelectedIndex();
                if(personNumber >= 0){
                    Person p = people.get(personNumber);
                    p.setPhoneNumber("");
                    refreshPeopleList();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void refreshPeopleList() {
        listPeopleModel.removeAllElements();
        for (Person p : people) {
            System.out.println("Adding Person to list" + p.getName());
            listPeopleModel.addElement(p.getName());
        }
    }

    public void addPerson(Person p) {
        people.add(p);
        refreshPeopleList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Screen screen = new Screen();
        screen.setVisible(true);
        Person pete = new Person( "Pete", "pete@gmail.com","555 001","balam","22/02/1999" );
        Person shay = new Person( "shay", "shay@gmail.com","111 001","balaam","22/02/1998");
        Person lori = new Person( "lori", "lori@gmail.com","222 001","balaaam","22/02/1997");
        Person thai = new Person( "thai", "thai@gmail.com","333 001","balaaam","22/02/1996");
        Person mel = new Person( "mel", "mel@gmail.com","444 001","bylam","22/02/1995");
        Person Mantas = new Person( "Mantas", "mantaskietas@gmail.com","999 111","bylammmm","09/03/2007");

        screen.addPerson(pete);
        screen.addPerson(shay);
        screen.addPerson(lori);
        screen.addPerson(thai);
        screen.addPerson(mel);
        screen.addPerson(Mantas);
    }
}
```

[my contact form layout photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eks7f.png)

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener for your delete button. Use an ActionListener (like buttonNew)

Comment: Oh! Thank You:) i tried using it and putting it like: p.setPhoneNumber=(“”) or (null) but neither worked:/. Maybe You could provide some suggestions? If You have some spare time, I would really appreciate it:)

Comment: *"Maybe You could provide some suggestions?"* This is a Q&A site, not a help desk. If you cannot solve this from the hint in the comment of  @DevilsHnd, I suggest posting a [mre] of your best attempt. It would have one `JList` with two items, one or two text fields to clear, and a button for 'delete'. That would take far less than the 133 lines of code seen above. *"my contact form layout photo"* There's nothing in that image which could not be adequately described in words, just like you .. ***did*** describe in words.